# Java String.Format Specifications

Tags: java, printf, string.format

I've spent a while searching google. It has lead to a few articles from here, and elsewhere.
I'm looking to use the string format engine (or w.e it should be called - please give me the proper term if you know it) to get the end of an input string rather than the start of the string..

Example:

```
System.out.printf("[%tY/%<tm/%<td-%<tH.%<tM.%<tS][%-20.20s] %s%n", new Date(), "long.string.class.test.TestClass", "Content Test...");
```

Outputs:

```
[2017/12/05-21.49.11]"[long.string.class.te] Content Test...
```

Whereas I want:

```
[2017/12/05-21.49.11]"[class.test.TestClass] Content Test...
```

In addition, I was curious if it's possible to also replace the first 3 characters with '...' should the string exceed the 20 character limit..

Comment: So you want the 20 characters starting from the right side of `"long.string.class.test.TestClass"` ? This sounds like you really want something different from what you asked. What is it you actually need to do?

Comment: I flagged this as a duplicate, check out the other question and answers to see if they help you.

Comment: @xtratic, The answer to your question is yes. In addition, I'm looking to do this via String.format which is why I titled and tagged it the way I did. Apologies if its a waste of time or unclear.

Comment: @xtratic while I will agree that this is a duplicate of that, it would appear that the solution doesn't use the String.format to complete the task, can you help do this via the formatter by any chance?

Comment: it's fine. I think `printf()` calls `String.format()` anyway, I don't have Java source in front of me though. I'm adding an answer since I've a little more to type. Or that, Jim's post is basically what I was gonna say.

Comment: printf does call String.format, but the linked article also uses String.substring, which is the part that I was looking to avoid, though I apparently can't, as indicated by answer supplied by @Jim-Garrison.

Comment: Yep, exactly what I was going to post. It kinda sucks that functionality isn't built into the formatter.

Comment: Agreed. With how often you see that functionality in logs and console output, you'd think that it would be by now; Especially given the fact that the formatter hasn't seemed to have progressed in years whereas most other things have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do that solely in the format string, you have to pass the text you want to print.  That's not exactly hard...

```
    String[] data = { "a short string", "a very long string to see that we get only the last 20 characters" };

    for (String s : data)
    {
        System.out.println("....:....|....:....|");
        System.out.printf("%20s\n",s.substring(Math.max(0, s.length()-20)));
    }
```

Adjust to `%s` if you don't want a fixed length, and `%-20s` to left-justify if you want.

Output:

```
....:....|....:....|
      a short string
....:....|....:....|
e last 20 characters
```

Comment: Fair enough, I was hoping for something using only the formatter but thanks for this. Sorry for the waste of time.